# unable to get scim 2.0 wso2 is api for get Roles under secondary user store

Tags: wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

I have a secondary userstore (JDBC) created in wso2 IS 5.11.0.
2 roles are added under the userstore.
I am using the below SCIM 2.0 api to get the roles.
https://{IS_IP}:(PORT}/t/carbon.super/scim2/Roles, but only the roles created under primary user store is listed in the response.

Under the claims list -> http://wso2.org/claims -> Role -> Mapped attributes, I have added the secondary user store to the list. still not getting the response.

Is there any other configuration to be done to get it via scim api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since WSO2 IS-5.11.0 Groups and Roles are considered separately. Refer [[1]](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/setup/migrating-what-has-changed/#group-and-role-separation)

`https://{IS_HOST}:(PORT}/scim2/Groups` endpoint lists out the userstore groups (both primary and secondary user stores' groups)

`https://{IS_HOST}:(PORT}/scim2/Roles` endpoint lists out the Roles (Roles are basically Internal and Application Roles. You won't see any prefix for Internal roles in the list)

In your case, since you have added a userstore group, it need to be managed via `https://{IS_HOST}:(PORT}/scim2/Groups`.